# In app products for in app currency

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've not built an android app for in app purchases before. I've been doing a bunch of reading and it looks like, there's two kinds of products: managed product and subscription.

I don't want to pick the wrong one because it looks like some of these are permanent, so I want to get it right out of the gate. The docs say that managed products are one time and belong to the user forever and so, I think maybe I need a subscription.

Subscription, though, would indicate renewal and that isn't right either. I did find some documentation that says you can mark a purchase as consumed. Is that for subscriptions or managed products?

This is common enough that I'm sure lots of people have solved it, but searches for in-app products currencies returns information about conversion to other currencies.

I'm working through the docs and currently here: https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html and why doesn't that talk about managed products and subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html after much searching. In it it indicates that you can only consume managed products, so that seems to be what I want.